# Automatically populate all properties of an Objective C instance with a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, introspection

I have a class with properties that I would like to set values from a dictionary.

In other words, I would like to automate this:

```
objectInstace.val1 = [dict objectForKey:@"val1"];
objectInstace.val2 = [dict objectForKey:@"val2"];
```

with something like this (pseudo code):

```
for key, value in dict:
    setattr(objectInstance, key, value)
```

Comment: It's OK to admit it's python (although you need an .iteritems() or .items() in there :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Key-Value Coding method [`setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:). It does precisely what you want. Just `[someObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:propertiesDictionary]`.

Answer (score 0):

ok unless I'm missing something why not create a method like:

setObjectProperties: (id) Object withValues:(NSDictionary *)dict

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but this seems like it should work:

For each `key` in the dictonary:

```
NSString* setMethod = "set" + [key capitalizedString] + ":";  // This is pseudo-code.
SEL setSelector = NSSelectorFromString(setMethod);
[objectInstance performSelector:setSelector withObject:[dict objectForKey:key]];
```

(The code to form `setMethod` is pseudo-code & left as an exercise because Obj-C string manipulation is horrible.)

Comment: This is just reinventing the KVC wheel.

Comment: It certainly is! I recommend voting for the accepted answer (which was news to me).