# Set the properties of an NSObject from the values in an NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, declared-property

I would like to know if it is possible to set the properties of an `NSObject` from an `NSDictionary` without setting each one individually.

The property names in the `NSObject` match the key names in the `NSDictionary`.

Is there an easy way of doing this?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create NSObject from NSDictionary in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349692/create-nsobject-from-nsdictionary-in-objective-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically populate all properties of an Objective C instance with a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760689/automatically-populate-all-properties-of-an-objective-c-instance-with-a-dictiona)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the types for the values match, you want to use `- (void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues`
 NSNull values will be treated as nil.

Comment: This is assuming you have the proper types stored in the dictionary.

Comment: True, I'll make a note of that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small library that automates this, it also handles conversion of dates
https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper

It automatically converts NSDictionary to NSObject as long as all keys are the same as property names.

```
Customer *customer = [Customer objectFromDictionary:customerDictionary];
NSArray *customers = [Customer objectFromDictionary:listOfCustomersDictionary];
```

if the key and property names are not the same you can write mapping

```
[mappingProvider mapFromDictionaryKey:@"dob" toPropertyKey:@"dateOfBearth" forClass:[Customer class]];
```